Unable to Add Omnichannel to Existing Environment
I have Customer Service Enterprise and a Digital Messaging Add-On trial, and I’m the Global Tenant Admin. Despite this, I’m still unable to add Omnichannel to my existing environment.
What could be the possible solutions or workarounds?

I previously created a new environment with Contact Center installed, but now I want to add those capabilities to my existing environment.
